# While loop to test if a file exists in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a shell script that does certain changes on a txt file only if it does  exist, however this test loop doesn't work, I wonder why?
Thank you!

```
while [ ! -f /tmp/list.txt ] ;
do
      sleep 2
done
```

Comment: I can't say that I'm surprised; that loop doesn't attempt to change anything.

Comment: The semi-colon is redundant.  In what way does that test loop not work?  It will iteratively sleep for 2 seconds until the file /tmp/list.txt exists.

Comment: Works for me - the loop terminates when the file is created outside of the script.

Comment: in fact, this loop only serves to wait until the file is there, the rest of my script does the changes... :p

Comment: Then the while loop works, it's just me... sorry.

Comment: Given the "the while loop works; it's just me" comment, presumably this should be closed as 'no longer relevant', except that reason for closing is no longer available...?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

When you say "doesn't work", how do you know it doesn't work?

You might try to figure out if the file actually exists by adding:

```
while [ ! -f /tmp/list.txt ]
do
  sleep 2 # or less like 0.2
done
ls -l /tmp/list.txt
```

You might also make sure that you're using a Bash (or related) shell by typing 'echo $SHELL'. I think that CSH and TCSH use a slightly different semantic for this loop.

Comment: Why are you using inverted file check? Shouldn't while [ -f /tmp/list.txt ] be used instead?

Comment: @valentt No hew loop say literally "while NOT file exists do sleep" .. if you would remove the 'NOT' the loop would break instantly

Comment: in 1 line: `while [ ! -f /tmp/list.txt ]; do sleep 2; done; ls -l /tmp/list.txt`

Answer (score 60):

If you are on linux and have inotify-tools installed, you can do this:

```
file=/tmp/list.txt
while [ ! -f "$file" ]
do
    inotifywait -qqt 2 -e create -e moved_to "$(dirname $file)"
done
```

This reduces the delay introduced by sleep while still polling every "x" seconds. You can add more events if you anticipate that they are needed.

Comment: +1 for efficiency. Pooling with sleep is ugly. For folks not knowing inotifywait - it's in package inotify-tools.

Comment: That's an exceedingly handy tool. For anyone wondering why the loop, it's to deal with possible race conditions between creation and waiting and because inotifywait has `--exclude` to filter out filenames, but not `--include` to ignore everything _except_ the filename. The above command should use the `-qq` argument instead of `>&/dev/null` though.

Comment: t is the `--timeout`, not the frequency of checking, no? The point of inotifywait is that there is no polling

Comment: @AlexDean The timeout is to prevent a race condition. Polling with sleep is slow because the loop won't exit during the sleep, but inotifywait will exit before the timeout if it sees an event.

Comment: @yingted - according to http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait, "-t <seconds>, --timeout <seconds> Exit if an appropriate event has not occurred within <seconds> seconds". So -t 2 times out after 2 seconds

Comment: @AlexDean Yes, but it's necessary to prevent a TOCTTOU race condition. Otherwise, `inotifywait` could hang indefinitely if a file is created just before it starts listening for events.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, put the ! outside the brackets;

```
while ! [ -f /tmp/list.txt ];
do
    echo "#"
    sleep 1
done
```

Also, if you add an echo inside the loop it will tell you if you are getting into the loop or not.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version with a **timeout** so that after an amount of time the loop ends with an error:

```sh
# After 60 seconds the loop will exit
timeout=60

while [ ! -f /tmp/list.txt ];
do
  # When the timeout is equal to zero, show an error and leave the loop.
  if [ "$timeout" == 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: Timeout while waiting for the file /tmp/list.txt."
    exit 1
  fi

  sleep 1

  # Decrease the timeout of one
  ((timeout--))
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue and it lead me here so I just wanted to leave my solution for anyone who experiences the same.

I found that if I ran `cat /tmp/list.txt` the file would be empty, even though I was certain that there were contents being placed immediately in the file. Turns out if I put a `sleep 1;` just before the `cat /tmp/list.txt` it worked as expected. There must have been a delay between the time the file was created and the time it was written, or something along those lines.

My final code:

```
while [ ! -f /tmp/list.txt ];
do
    sleep 1;
done;
sleep 1;
cat /tmp/list.txt;
```

Hope this helps save someone a frustrating half hour!

Comment: In your specific use case, I would opt for `while ! [ -s /tmp/list.txt];
do sleep 1; 
done; 
cat /tmp/list.txt`<br/>

-s in while checks is the file is not 0 bytes, so this negates it to keep looping until it has data written. Alternatively, until is a good option too: `until [ -s /tmp/list.txt ]; do sleep 1; done; cat /tmp/list.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Like @zane-hooper, I've had a similar problem on NFS. On parallel / distributed filesystems the lag between you creating a file on one machine and the other machine "seeing" it can be very large, so I could wait up to a full minute after the creation of the file before the while loop exits (and there also is an aftereffect of it "seeing" an already deleted file).

This *creates the illusion that the script "doesn't work"*, while in fact it is the filesystem that is dropping the ball.

This took me a while to figure out, hope it saves somebody some time.

PS This also causes an annoying number of "Stale file handler" errors.

Answer (score 1):

works with bash and sh both:

```
touch /tmp/testfile
sleep 10 && rm /tmp/testfile &
until ! [ -f /tmp/testfile ]
do
   echo "testfile still exist..."
   sleep 1
done
echo "now testfile is deleted.."
```

Answer (score -3):

do it like this

```
while true
do
  [ -f /tmp/list.txt ] && break
  sleep 2
done
ls -l /tmp/list.txt
```