# While loop (or block) untill a file gets generated in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am having a batch file, in that i want to block untill a file gets generated. I got a sample script on [bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379829/while-loop-to-test-if-a-file-exists-in-bash). How we can do the same thing in batch script.

Answer (score 0):

This is the usual way of doing it.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "flagFile=c:\somewhere\list.txt"

:loop
    if not exist "%flagFile%" (
        ping -n 2 localhost > nul
        goto loop
    )

    echo File %flagFile% exists

    endlocal
```

For a non `goto` version

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "flagFile=c:\somewhere\list.txt"
    (cd.|for /l %%a in (0 0 1) do @(dir "%flagFile%">nul 2>nul && exit || ping -n 2 localhost > nul ))

    echo File %flagFile% exists

    endlocal
```

This spawns a separate copy of cmd that will loop until the file exists, with a 1 second pause between checks.