# Is there a good way to detect MySQL is "ready?"

Tags: mysql

I am not a MySQL expert.

I have a script that installs MySQL, starts `mysqld`, and then uses `mysql` to do some initialization.

Currently, in order to have this work, I enter into a loop that (apologize for the pseudocode mixing multiple languages):

```
mysqld_safe /* ... */ & /* ampersand to start in background so we can continue */
while(fileDoesNotExist("/tmp/mysql.sock")) {
    sleepFor100ms();
}
mysql -u root /* and so forth */ initialize.sql
```

This seems to work (!) but has multiple problems:

- polling smells funny,
- I am not smart enough about MySQL to know whether looking at that hard-coded pathname `/tmp/mysql.sock` is smart at all.

And yet it's a lot easier than trying to (for example) consume and parse the stdout (or is it stderr?) of `mysqld_safe` to figure out whether the server has started.

My narrow question is whether there's a way to issue a blocking start of `mysqld`: can I issue any command that blocks until the database has started, and then exits (and detaches, maybe leaving a PID file), and has a companion stop command? (Or maybe allows me to read the PID file and issue my own SIGTERM?)

My broader question is, am I on the right track, or is there some totally different and easier (to be "easier" for me it would have to be lightweight; I'm not that interested in installing a bunch of tools like Puppet or DbMaintain/Liquibase or whatever) approach to solving the problem I articulated? That is, starting with a `.gz` file containing MySQL, install a userland MySQL and initialize a database?

Comment: There's no need to be or not be an expert to ask a question here.

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming thought. I just thought it would be helpful for context, so people wouldn't talk over my head. :)

Comment: Would [polling to see if a file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379829/while-loop-to-test-if-a-file-exists-in-bash) be a step in the right direction?

Comment: haha, as you'll see, I'm already doing that. :) I'm asking if there's a *better* solution.

Comment: Wasn't sure if you didn't know a shell way of doing that. What's so bad about being patient and waiting for the file to appear? The location of this file is not easy to divine, but may be defined in `/etc/my.cnf` depending on your platform.

Comment: Usually if I am polling for something I figure I'm doing something wrong; there's a waste of resources, etc. It seems hacky all-around. If it's the only way, it's the only way, but it makes me guess I'm not understanding things. :)

Comment: Computers do billions of operations per second these days. Testing for a file and sleeping isn't a waste of resources. It'd be hard to measure the impact of that file test on your system.

Comment: No, I understand, I'm not being a performance zealot. But, for example, if my assumption is wrong (that /tmp/mysql.sock will eventually be created), perhaps because I have the pathname wrong or whatever, then I will go into an infinite loop. So then I have to make it more complicated, exit with error after some number of repetitions that I guess at, and so forth, and so forth. So yeah, I'm looking for the cleanest solution.

Comment: Hello David, so what did you end up using? I'm currently doing exactly the same thing and also thought of polling whether the file exists. Have you found "cleaner" solution?

Comment: Hi @user1762087 -- see my comments under the accepted answer. I ended up using the PID file because, since I control the installation and thus the configuration, I can just look in the default PID file location, which turned out to be pretty simple.

Comment: thank you. Since I also know the location of the .sock file I will check for both .pid and .sock file, to be absolutely certain that mysql is in ready state (in case that .pid file is created sooner than .sock file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the init shell script for mysqld. They do polling, in a function called wait_for_pid().

That function checks for the existence of the pid file, and if it doesn't exist yet, sleeps for 1 whole second, then tries again. There's a timeout that defaults to 900 seconds, at which point it gives up waiting and concludes that it's not going to start (and outputs a totally unhelpful message "The server quit without updating PID file").

You don't have to guess where the pid file is. If you're starting mysqld_safe, you should *tell it* where it should create the pid file, using the `--pid-file` option.

One tricky part is that the pid file isn't created until mysqld initializes. This can take a while if it has to perform crash recovery using the InnoDB log files, and the log files are large. So it could happen that 900 seconds of timeout isn't long enough, and you get a spurious error, even though mysqld successfully starts a moment after the timeout.

You can also read the error log or the console output of mysqld. It should eventually output a line that says "ready for connections."

To read until you get this line, and then terminate the read, you could use:

```
tail -f | sed -e '/ready for connections/q'
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess my way was closer to the best way than I thought, but I appreciate the advice on the PID file. Two things I prefer about that solution: (1) even if I choose to "guess" the location (mysqld_safe seems to choose a default path which is derived from the installation directory), it means that if I have multiple installs, I won't mistake one for another, (2) as you mentioned, I can explicitly specify the path for clarity or robustness. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the PID file has a default location in the data directory. That default can be overridden in one or more my.cnf files too. So guessing is difficult. Better to specify the location, which will override any setting in my.cnf or the built-in default.

Comment: For my use case, I'm doing the installation, so some of the dangers you cite are less important for me, and I may decide that the simplicity of DRY is better; in my case, I only care *once* where the PID file is, and that's during my installation script when I'm initializing the database. So as long as *my* execution of mysqld_safe puts it in a predictable location, I'll know what PID file to detect (rather than repeating it on the command line and in the polling loop), so that would make the script as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
mysqladmin -h localhost status
```

or use a pure bash solution like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it)

```
./wait-for-it.sh --timeout 10 -h localhost -p 3306
```